# Shell command to set tmux clipboard

Tags: tmux, clipboard

I sometimes run a command like this to set the system clipboard, because I want to paste the result of `whatevercommand` into a text editor, terminal, or whatnot.

```
whatevercommand | xclip -selection c
```

But this uses the X clipboard, and if I'm on a remote system with no X, this won't work. Instead I often use tmux on remote systems.

So is there a similar command that I can use to set tmux's clipboard?

I'm thinking something like:

```
whatevercommand | tmux set-clipboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|tmux load-buffer -
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I meant. Unfortunately I didn't think enough before asking, because I realized that what I actually wanted to do this time was to copy/paste between remote connections, where the remote machine is not running tmux. Oh well, that's another question maybe.